# Mounting AWS EFS with NFS on macOS

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, mount, amazon-efs

I'm trying to mount an EFS volume with NFS on macOS, but am having permissions trouble. I am running the following command to mount the volume:

```sh
sudo mount -t nfs -o vers=4 -o tcp -w <IP Address>:/ efs/
```

and am able to successfully mount the volume, but it mounts with `root` privileges, and I need to be able to grant access to the volume to the local user. I need the local user to be able to both read and write to the volume.

Trying to `chown -R $(whoami) ./efs` results in an `Unknown error: 10039`.

I can successfully `chmod 666` the files inside of the mount (sometimes with odd behaviors), but I ultimately need to just grant the local user write access to the volume.

Am I missing an option in the `mount` command or does anyone know how to mount the efs volume and provide the local user permissions to it?